# How to display data in custom table using asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, aspxgridview

I  want to display data from my SQL database in a custom table format.  So basically this is what I would like to achieve:

A. To display all entries in SQL table in a gridview with a `view` button next to each row

B. Click on the `view` button to display the below in a new web page

```
 ______________________________________
|           Customer Info              |
----------------------------------------
|Customer Name:   "From DB Table"      |
|Address:         "From DB Table"      |
----------------------------------------
```

Then the next `table` below the one above

```
 ______________________________________
|           Customer Network           |
----------------------------------------
|Network Location:   "From DB Table"   |
|APs:                "From DB Table"   |
----------------------------------------
```

All of the above is from one `ID` in my SQL DB table.  So I want to break it up into sections to display all the data in the SQL Table

I don't have any code yet as I am not sure on how to do this.

To sum up: 
When the page loads it the shows all the entries in the database in a `gridview` with a view button next to each row

Then when the user clicks on the `view` button it opens a new page with the above table.

Thanks

**CODE**

GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Then Code Behind

```
                GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OfficeConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DisplayName 'Display Name', Replace(PrimaryEmailAddress,'SMTP:', ' ') 'Email Address', Replace(Licenses,'reseller-account:', ' ') 'License Type', LastPasswordChangeTimestamp 'Last Password Reset' FROM Consulting ", con))
            {
                for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[i][1] == DBNull.Value)
                        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                }
                dt.AcceptChanges();
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adpt.Fill(dt);
            }

        }
        return dt;
    }
}
}
```

This is some code from a different section in my web app.  I can use the same code with a few changes, but how do I add the View button and to achieve the above question?

Comment: Please share what you have done so far. Code, SQL scripts, ..

Comment: I dont have any code apart from adding the data to sql.  I am using  fieldsets as it is quite a lot of information to add.  That all works great but just need a tutorial or example on what I want to achieve.

Comment: "B. Click on the view button to display the below in a new web page" So you want to do the "Open new Form/Window" pattern? I can only advise against it for WebApplications. In Forms and WPF, those two at least still belong to the same App domain, so they can interact (like one being a modal dialog to the other. But two webpages got nothing to do with one another. This is just asking for Race Conditions because the user forgot he had (another copy) open.

Comment: @Christopher what are you talking about?!?

Comment: @dpant Wich part of my comment do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. This should work:

**Customers.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />                    
        <%--add other data fields here--%>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Text="View" 
            DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" 
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/View.aspx?id={0}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetData();
    }
}

private void GetData()
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection([YOUR CONNECTION STRING]))
    {
        con.Open();
        // replace with your query
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,Name,Email,Address FROM Customers", con))
        {
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            GridView1.DataSource = dr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }           
}
```

B. The "view" page accepts the customer ID as parameter to display his details in any html layout you like, for example:

**View.aspx**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Customer Info</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Name:</td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Address" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Customer Network</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Email" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Network Location:</td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="NetLocation" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetData();
    }
}

private void GetData()
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection([YOUR CONNECTION STRING]))
    {
        con.Open();
        // replace with your query
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Name,Email,Address FROM Customers WHERE ID={Request["id"]}", con))
        {
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Name.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
                Address.Text = dr["Address"].ToString();
                Email.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
                // etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As said, you can replace both the code to fetch data from the database and the HTML layout with anything you like. This is the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Look up gridview CommandFields. You can use them to have the gridview generate a button for each row, and then hook into the OnRowCommand event of the gridview.

Here's a couple examples I found just on a quick google search, with some different ways to do this, that might help get you started.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564619/Example-of-gridview-rowcommand-on-Button-Click

http://ezzylearning.com/tutorial/using-button-columns-in-gridview

In the OnRowCommand code, you can redirect the user to a new page, or show a different panel on the same page, however you prefer to handle switching views to the details view.